# I can not install MySQL using yum on Centos7

Tags: linux, centos, yum, mysql

I've installed `centos7` recently, but, when I am trying to install `MySQL` using the command:

```
yum install mysql-community-server
```

I keep getting Exiting on user cancel while I am not hitting any keyboard button. Here is the output:

```
install  2 Packages (+9 Dependent packages)
 Total size: 80 M Total download size: 79 M Is this ok [y/d/N]: y 
    Downloading packages: 
    No Presto metadata available for base No Presto metadata available for mysql56-community mysql-community-client-5.6.24-3.el7.x86_64.rpm |7.6 MB     00:32 ...  mysql-community-server-5.6.24-3.el7.x86_64.rpm        |  46MB     00:41 ...  mysql-community-libs-5.6.24-3.el7.x86_64.rpm      |    0 B     00:30 ...  (1/9): mysql-community-cli 0% [                ] 4.7 kB/s | 159 kB  283:33 ETA 

    Exiting on user cancel
```

What is the problem? Why I can not install it? What is the solution?

Note: My yum has the following plugins: fastmirror, axelget, langpacks.

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox?

Comment: no, I am not using Virtualbox, I have centos7 installed beside windows7 on my laptop

Comment: Did you try that command I have written in answer?

Comment: You need to use MariaDB as MySql is not used any more by redhat-like distros. See one of the answers bellow

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning `yum`:

```
yum clean all
```

Hope you have done this:

Create a new file `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo` with the desired version.

For 5.7, add the lines below:

```
[mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

For 5.6, add the lines below:

```
[mysql56-community]
name=MySQL 5.6 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

(use `.../el/6/...` for CentOS 6)

Then try the below command:

```
yum install mysql-community-server
```

Comment: Are you behind a web proxy? Try adding http_caching=packages to your /etc/yum.conf and see if that helps.

Comment: keeping gpgcheck=1 will give the below error

 Failing package is: mysql-community-server-5.7.38-1.el7.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql 
to avoid that keep gpgcheck=0

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. RedHat Enterprise Linux and its derivatives have shifted to MariaDB from MySQL. So you can install mariadb-server on CentOS7 using this command `yum install mariadb-server mariadb`. Here is a good step by step tutorial how you can do this in p.8 [Install MariaDB Database](http://www.tecmint.com/things-to-do-after-minimal-rhel-centos-7-installation/2/) or you can use this source for that [Mariadb step by step](http://www.server180.com/2014/09/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7-step.html)

Answer (score 0):

try `$sudo yum update`

then if you correctly configure mirrors it will update packege db.

try install mysql once more using `$sudo yum install mysql-community-server`

if you don't have sudo installed then `$su`

and install sudo `#yum install sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sudo bash -c 'yum clean metadata && yum upgrade'
```

After that install.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the relevant repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`? It is not by default on my CentOS7 system. They've made it easy for you to install this first: Go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/ and download the file and install it "manually" with `rpm`. Then your yum command should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `yum` gives you the wrong error because of one bug. To solve it and see the real error, you need to apply this fix I found [here](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=47372&start=10).

> There is a bug in python-urlgrabber that is used by yum that results
>   in the wrong error being generated. It was noticed during the el7 beta
>   and reported but it appears not to have been fixed. The problem is
>   that the mirror that you are connecting to is interrupting the
>   connection and yum currently sees that as an error and terminates
>   rather than just trying another mirror.
>
> If you don't mind editing files that are meant to be owned by the `rpm`
>   then you can fix this or at least mitigate its effects. Edit
>   `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py` and find line
>   1510 where it currently says:
>
> `python CODE: SELECT ALL
>               elif errcode in (42, 55, 56):`
>
> and change that back to what it was before
>
> `python CODE: SELECT ALL
>               elif errcode == 42:`